# Converting a decimal value into a hex value with the same visible representation

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, data-conversion

I am working on a microcontroller which only outputs number in a hexadecimal representation. I have data which is calculated in decimal and is meant for a human to read and interpret. My output is the three decimal numbers 45, 27, and 91, when I output these I get 0x2D, 0x1B, and 0x5B. What operation can I perform to convert 45 to 0x45, 27 to 0x27 and so on.

Comment: Just stick `"0x"` string on the front... wait, do you mean for display output? What data type are you expecting for the result?

Comment: How do you output your variables? Via a serial interface, or debug logs, or a display or something different?

Comment: @musefan These values are computed during runtime. So 45 is the decimal value that I want people to see from the output. These are all outputted as unsigned chars.

Comment: @izlin the outupt comes through a serial interface through USB

Comment: " My output is the three decimal numbers 45, 27, 91"   so when you get 4A, how does that work?  0x45 and 45 are not the same

Comment: @Ron I don't think I can use streams as the hex characters are packed into a response which is then sent through USB, they are not directly output from my code. What I mean is that if I have the decimal number 45 which I want to put out through the USB wire. To show this I have to output the number 69 which is 0x45

Comment: please show your code. converting 27 to 0x27 only makes sense in a string representation, because decimal 27 is not the same as hex 27, so maybe you simply have to prepend "0x" to your output. However, I wonder where you got the 27 from. Do you calculate it yourself? You dont need to do that, but simply take the original value and use an output manipulator (`std::hex`)

Comment: @UKMonkey: The old folks will know this format as BCD, Binary Coded Decimal.  When you get 0x4A hex, you convert it to 0x74 BCD.

Comment: @MSaltersThanks - learn something new everyday, AND nice to feel young again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
unsigned char convert(unsigned char in) {
    return ((in % 10) * 0x01) + ((in / 10) * 0x10);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 45;
    printf ("0x%02X", convert(a)); // prints "0x45"
    return 0;
}
```

It converts the decimal value `45` to `0x45` which is equivalent to decimal `69`.
Note that the convert function is not really fast on microcontrollers because of the division `/`.

It can only print decimal values from 0 to 99 because there are only two digits to use.

Comment: i am a bit confused... why all this voodoo instead of `std::cout << "0x" << 45;` ?

Comment: @user463035818 If I understood the question right he needs to send the value via a serial interface. That's why the OP asked to convert 45 to 69 that you can see 0x45 on the serial stream.

Comment: still dont get it completely but sounds reasonable

Comment: Hi, thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! Sorry if I didn't word it properly

Answer (score 1):

Though I think it is not a good idea to convert 45 to 0x45, here is the method:

```
int dec = 45;
int hex = 0;
int i = 1;
while(dec/10 != 0){
    int digit = dec%10;
    hex += digit*i;
    i *=16;
}
cout << hex << endl;// if you convert "hex" to hexadecimal, it would be 0x45
```